# Install Matplotlib on Mac for python3

Tags: matplotlib

I have both python2 and python3 on my mac but when I go to install matplotlib it installs on the python2 anaconda version. How do I install it on the python3 version for my mac. I have seen something in windows where you go to where the installation is before you run the terminal code, but I am new to all this so I'm not sure. Appreciate any help. Thx.

Comment: Here is the error in python3

Comment: >> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'